# LED upgrade for cooker hood (12 V AC to 240 V AC or 12 V DC)

Tags: led, transformer, rectifier, appliances

I've got a cooker hood with some problematic 2x 12 V 20 W G4 bulb downlights. I want to replace them with LEDs. Unfortunately the units are physically too small to accommodate suitable LED G4s. 
Therefore, I'm considering replacing the whole downlight units with LED ones.

The problem I have is any downlight units I find are either 240v AC (I'm in UK) or 12V DC, requiring a driver. However, the supply to the bulbs is currently 12V AC, rather than DC.

I looked to see if I could just use 240V units, but unfortunately the switch is a soft switch, which operates a PCB-mounted relay-switched 240v to 12v transformer which looks a bit awkward to remove from the board.

What would be a sensible option? Thoughts I've had are:

- 12V AC -> DC rectifier, although not entirely sure whether heat dissipation would become an issue (2x LED units draw about 6W)
- Use 12 V AC with AC relay to switch a new parallel 240 V feed to the new units. Possible problem with this is that I imagine it'll reduce efficiency and defeat the purpose of doing this and also the transformer buzzes with no load so if there's only a relay as the load it might still buzz. Plus the AC relays seem expensive...
- bite the bullet and desolder the current AC transformer and try and use the existing relay output to switch a new standard 12 V DC LED driver (only reluctant to do this because I'm a (lapsed!) physicist rather than an electronics person and a bit nervous I'll trash an otherwise sound PCB!

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: There exists miniscule G4 LEDs. Are you sure there isn't an off-the-shelf product available as is?

Comment: As winny says: https://i.imgur.com/Z4jiYSu.png

Comment: That would probably fit. However, the contacts are a bit rubbish in the current units and one only makes an intermittent connection, despite cleaning.
This has, though, made me realise a 4th possibly easier option exists - just get replacement G4 downlights and make sure they're big enough to accommodate LED replacements. So easy to overthink things sometimes... :)

Comment: The 'cooker hood' location implies heat. LEDs do *not* like heat! You may end up replacing those LEDs more often than the old incandescents...